# Subclassing NSScrollView drawRect: Method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, drawing, nsview

I'm customizing the UI for one of my apps, and the idea is that a text area is initially bordered gray when out of focus, and when it comes into focus, the border becomes bright white. My app uses a dark theme, and for a single-lined `NSTextField`, this works great.

I'm running into problems with a subclassed `NSTextView`, however. In order to alter the border properly, I ended up having to actually subclass the parent `NSScrollView`, but am still seeing strange behavior. *(See screenshot below.)* I **want** the red box to fill the entire scroll view, as this would allow me to stroke (instead of filling, which is just for testing) the path, producing a nice border. Instead, the red box seems to be only filling to the internal child view.

The following code snippet, which is for the `NSScrollView` subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSRect borderRect = self.bounds;
    borderRect.origin.y += 1;
    borderRect.size.width -= 1;
    borderRect.size.height -= 4;

    BOOL inFocus = ([[self window] firstResponder] == self);

    if (!inFocus) {
        inFocus = [self anySubviewHasFocus:self];
    }

    if (inFocus) {
        [[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:.8 green:.2 blue:0 alpha:1] set];
    } else {
        [[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:.1 green:.8 blue:0 alpha:1] set];
    }

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setShouldAntialias:NO];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:borderRect];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    NSLog(@"My bounds: %@", NSStringFromRect(borderRect));
    NSLog(@"Super (%@) bounds: %@", [self superview], NSStringFromRect(borderRect));
}
```

Produces the screenshot as seen below. Also, see the output in the log, which *suggests* that the entire view should be filled. This is the only output that is ever shown, regardless of the size of the text inside. Entering carriage returns increases the height of the **red** box, but does not produce different output. (And I would like the **red** box to fill the entire bounds.)

```
2011-04-08 21:30:29.789 MyApp[6515:903] My bounds: {{0, 1}, {196, 87}}
2011-04-08 21:30:29.789 MyApp[6515:903] Super (<EditTaskView: 0x3a0b150>) bounds: {{0, 1}, {196, 87}}
```

[image: Drawing Issue]

**Edit:** Thanks to **Josh Caswell** for his answer. See below for the proper behavior when not focused, and when focused.

[image: No Focus]

[image: Focus]

Comment: Do you want the border always be completely visible, or do you want it to only be visible in the areas where the edge of the text view is visible?

Comment: Good question. I want the border to always be visible, around the bounds of the scroll view. (Not the bounds of the text view.) The border will always be visible, but will be a light gray when not the first responder, and will be bright white when it has focus. (It's on a dark background.)

Comment: This is probably a problem with clipping. Find the current clipping rect using `CGContextGetClipBoundingBox((CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort]);` and post what it is. You might be able to solve the problem by not calling `[super drawRect:]`, which would be ok since NSScrollView usually doesn't do any drawing anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ughoavgfhw noted, `NSScrollView` doesn't usually do any drawing, and probably has a weird interaction with its child views in that way. I'd suggest putting something like the following in your text view's drawing code to draw this custom focus ring that you want*:

```
// We're going to be modifying the state for this, 
// so allow it to be restored later
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

// Choose the correct color; isFirstResponder is a custom     
// ivar set in becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder
if( isFirstResponder && [[self window] isKeyWindow]){
    [myFocusedColor set];
} 
else {
    [myNotFocusedColor set];
}

// Create two rects, one slightly outset from the bounds,
// one slightly inset
NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
NSRect innerRect = NSInsetRect(bounds, 2, 2);
NSRect outerRect = NSMakeRect(bounds.origin.x - 2, 
                              bounds.origin.y - 2,
                              bounds.size.width + 4,
                              bounds.size.height + 4);

// Create a bezier path using those two rects; this will
// become the clipping path of the context
NSBezierPath * clipPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:outerRect];
[clipPath appendBezierPath:[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:innerRect]];

// Change the current clipping path of the context to 
// the enclosed area of clipPath; "enclosed" defined by 
// winding rule. Drawing will be restricted to this area.
// N.B. that the winding rule makes the order that the
// rects were added to the path important.
[clipPath setWindingRule:NSEvenOddWindingRule];
[clipPath setClip];
// Fill the rect; drawing is clipped and the inner rect
// is not drawn in
[[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:outerRect] fill];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

This should be a reasonable approximation of what AppKit does when it draws a focus ring. Of course, AppKit is sort of allowed to draw outside a view's bounds -- I can't guarantee that this is *completely* safe, but you seem to get a margin of 3 px to play with. You could draw the ring entirely inside the bounds if you wanted. A true focus ring extends slightly (2 px) inside the view anyways (as I've done here).

Apple docs on [Setting the Clipping Region](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/GraphicsContexts/GraphicsContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH203-BCIIADBC).

EDIT: After re-reading your comments on the question, I realize I may have long-winded-ly buried the real answer. Try either subclassing `NSClipView` and switching your scroll view's clip view for that, or using a custom view for the document view.

---

<sub>*: You could also put this in the drawing code of a custom view subclass which is set as the document view of the `NSScrollView`; then your text view could be a subview of that. Or substitute a custom `NSClipView` subclass.</sub>

Comment: Perfect - all I actually had to do was create the NSBezier *clipPath with the bounds of the scroll view, then call setClip! Thanks!

Comment: @craig: I'm glad you were able to tease some useful information out of it!

Comment: You can use NSInsetRect for outerRect again by using NSRect outerRect = NSInsetRect(bounds, -2, -2)