# How to implement a custom Focus Ring in drawRect for NSTextField or NSTextVew

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, drawrect, nstextview

I want to draw a custom focus ring for my `NSTextView` subclass (which doesn't have a focus ring by default). I managed to implement it by overriding the parent `NSScrollView` `drawRect` and adding this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (focused) {
        NSSetFocusRingStyle(NSFocusRingOnly);
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    }

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

However, I want to draw my own, custom focus ring. I have searched and searched for examples of this, and tried messing around and writing it myself, to no avail. The biggest issue I have is the fact that it will get cropped to the `NSScrollView`/`NSTextView` frame, no matter how I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subclassing NSScrollView drawRect: Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602350/subclassing-nsscrollview-drawrect-method)

Comment: Almost, but that is just a block border. I need to replicate the NSFocusRing style of Cocoa controls.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this answer for 10.7+:

Now you should override `drawFocusRingMask` to render (simply drawing a shape; the system will take care of color/style), and override `focusRingMaskBounds` to hint at its boundaries.  Also, call `noteFocusRingMaskChanged` if you change the shape in some way that the system could not figure out on its own.

---

***(Below is the previous answer, requiring older APIs:)***

In the Carbon framework there are `HIThemeBeginFocus()` and `HIThemeEndFocus()`, which allow you to cause any series of drawings (such as a rectangle or shape) to have an automatic "focused" appearance.  Requires Mac OS X 10.5 or later.

This uses Core Graphics directly.  To find the CG context from a `drawRect:` method in Cocoa, you'd do something like:

```
NSGraphicsContext* contextMgr = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
CGContextRef drawingContext = (CGContextRef)[contextMgr graphicsPort];
```

As far as avoiding clipping, one option is to use a parent view (such as an `NSBox` that has no border) to give extra padding.  Perform the custom drawing at an inset location in the parent view that won't be clipped; in other words, give the illusion that the view is a bit smaller than its actual rectangle.